# Login to ASP website before using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, asp-classic, authentication

I am using "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser" to parse data from a gaming ASP website. The data that i need to grab are only visible to registered users so i need something to log me in to site before start using it. Can someone suggest me a script or something which it can do this ? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You should split the login bit into a different question since it's unrelated to this one.

Comment: I don't want to post a non-answer, but I use both the SimpleXML and DomDocument all the time and have no issues (including with UTF-8 support). Apart from a couple of caveats, it's really easy to use and problem free. It's probably worth posting about the problem(s) you are having and seeing if you can get answers to them.

Comment: Thank all of you but i just found out that "mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");" made the trick :D Would be great if you help me with the login in to aspx website before using it now...

Comment: It does not matter if its an ASP website or php or whatever language they use. Login to website is almost always the same process - you submit a form with your username and password and get back the session cookie. Then on subsequent requests send that cookie in header. All this can be done using curl in php.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should post with:

```
<?php
function do_post_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
{
  $params = array('http' => array(
              'method' => 'POST',
              'content' => $data
            ));
  if ($optional_headers !== null) {
    $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
  }
  $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
  $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
  if (!$fp) {
    throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
  if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
  }
  return $response;
}
```

That should be able to send a post request. After that, you should be able to grab what you need.